# Detect if one of multiple processes has clicked a button

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc

I have the following setup:

- My application has a sticky button (i.e. clicking the button makes it stay down, until it's clicked again when it goes up).
- Multiple instances of the application can run concurrently.
- A "detector" application needs to be able to report whether or not at least one of the above buttons is currently down.
- There can be a limit to how many instances are supported, but clicking the button once the limit is exceeded should gracefully fail.

How can I do this, using Windows API calls?   So far I have used `CreateSemaphore`, however that has an insurmountable problem that if the application is killed, the semaphore count is not incremented (so the button is still reported as down even when all applications are closed).

Comment: How frequently do you need to detect? Could you just poll the instances and ask them (via a message)?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Not very often, but it seems like there should be an easier solution than that

Comment: `So far I have used CreateSemaphore` - the most simply and effective way for this place `LONG g_nCount` in shared section and use `InterlockedIncrement`/`InterlockedDecrement` on press button. but this of course not help in case if process will be external terminated

Comment: The most reliable solution is to just poll the currently running windows when needed. I suggest having all of the apps call `RegisterWindowMessage()` to obtain a unique message ID, and then the detector can broadcast that message when it needs to, and any app instance that has a button pressed down can respond to that message.

Comment: exist absolute reliable solution if use Lpc ports(undocumented, but more simply and native here) or pipes (more complex). server application create port or pipes(multiple). clients connect to port/pipe. when user click button - client ask server, which maintaining total "sticky" count and pressed/unpressed for every client. sense - even if some client process terminated - server got notify (`LPC_PORT_CLOSED` or `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`) and if this died process use resource before termination - decrement "sticky" count.

Comment: @RbMm and if the server (detector) app is not running, the clients have to continuously poll and reconnect to it until successful. It makes the client apps needlessly more complex. They could just broadcast a unique message whenever a button is clicked, and the detector could pick that up while it is running. And it could broadcast a poll message when it first starts running. Much simpler then a client/server model.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - this is already design details. may be clients app must connect to server at start, and if this fail - just exit. of course possible different implementations. i describe one of possible how i view